# Is there a RTL function like StringOfChar which duplicates strings instead of chars?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am using the StringOfChar function to create a string of chars like this

```
S := StringOfChar('b', 5); //s is set to 'bbbbb'
```

Is there any RTL function that does the same (like StringofString('abc',3) must return 'abcabcabc' ), but accepts a string as parameter instead of char? 
I can write a function like that but I'm looking for an existing RTL function.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

the function which you are looking for is [`StrUtils.DupeString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/StrUtils.DupeString)

```
s:=DupeString('abc',3)
```

will return

```
'abcabcabc'
```